# Editing my child theme

Tags: magento2, php, header, home, parent-child-theme

I've created a **child theme** by adding files to `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\Magento\themename`

In this, I have a `theme.xml` file, a `registration.php` file, web folder, media folder and a `Magento_Theme` folder.

**My question is as follows:**

This child theme is using the `C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank` structure. For my homepage, how would I change the header file for example? It has a top menu, a search and a logo. How would I be able to re-arrange this?

Or even the homepage. How would I make a new layout for this, to maybe have a **3/5** column of normal content and **2/5** content of the latest products (As an example)?

Any directions would be awesome!

Comment: You have to do customization to layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to add Magento_catalog module from vendor to your theme

**Step1.** Create folder name Magento_Catalog

**Step2.** Copy web, template and layout folder in that folder

**Step3.** If you want to create new XML create default.xml to make changes